# plotly is undefined in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am creating a weather app in react which shows the weather forcast in a graph using the api but i am getting an error plotly is undefined although i have pasted cdn of plotly in my index.html

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />


    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />

    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />

   <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>


  </body>
</html>
```

plot.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export class Plot extends Component {

    drawPlot = () => {
        Plotly.newPlot('plot',[{
            x:this.props.xData,
            y:this.props.yData,
            type: this.props.type

        }],
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it is undefined in your global scope, try to console Plotly object outside of the component.
If you're using Webpack for bundling try to install Plotly as an NPM package.
Then import it to your project with ES6 import

Comment: i installed plotly using npm install plotly command  in my folder but it is still giving me the same error

Comment: You can also try to use react-plotly https://plot.ly/javascript/react/ as well

Answer (score 1):

It is undefined in the global scope, install plotly by npm.

**npm install plotly.js**

And import it in your as

```
import Plotly from 'plotly.js';
```

**[GitHub Reference](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js)**

Answer (score 0):

Install "plotly.js-dist" package from npm `npm install plotly.js-dist` and than `import Plotly from "plotly.js-dist";` in Plot.js component